# Problem with CancelIoEx function on some platforms

Tags: asynchronous, winapi, usb

I work with usb device and use async functions of usbdk driver for I/O operations. I have a problem with canceling of operations on some win platforms. Im using function CancelIoEx for that and it works fine for some part of users but for some it doesn't work. The data is either transmitted completely or not transmitted at all. No intermediate values. CancelIoEx returns 1 in both cases. AbortPipe by usbdk lib doesn't work at all.

```
HANDLE redirectHandle = usbdk_helper.StartRedirect(&devID);
HANDLE systemHandle = usbdk_helper.GetRedirectorSystemHandle(redirectHandle);
unsigned char* buffer = static_cast<unsigned char*>(std::malloc(0x08 + length));
OVERLAPPED overlapped;
USB_DK_TRANSFER_REQUEST request { 0 };
DWORD overlappedTransfered = 0;

overlapped.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, L"USBEVENT");

...
...
...

request.Buffer = buffer;
request.BufferLength = 0x08 + length;
request.TransferType = ControlTransferType;

auto res = usbdk_helper.WritePipe(redirectHandle, &request, &overlapped); //return TransferSuccessAsync
auto abort_res = CancelIoEx(systemHandle, &overlapped); //Return TRUE
auto event_res = WaitForSingleObject(overlapped.hEvent, INFINITE); //return WAIT_OBJECT_0
std::cout << "count transfered bytes: " << std::dec << request.Result.GenResult.BytesTransferred << std::endl; //0 or full for "bad", or 0 or intermediate for "correct"
```

Comment: Do you have a list of versions where it fails? Hardware?

Comment: @Anders, yes, it's win 10 x64 19044.
For some users with this system, cancel works well, but for some with the same system, it doesn't work.

Comment: Are you transferring enough data that a partial transfer actually makes sense? Because if you try cancelling after the operation has succeeded (even if you haven't yet been notified of that success) then cancelling isn't going to work.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, yes, I transfer over 1k bytes and after canceling it may be transferred completely or not transferred at all and for both cases CancelIoEx return TRUE

Comment: @SoronelHaetir, and as i told this problem not for all users, for some it works as it should (Transferred intermediate values between 0 and buffer size)

Comment: Whether some users can cancel and others not could come down to something as simple as system load. Even if the hardware and available (though not necessarily running) software is exactly the same between two systems if one has loads of unused cycles while the other is always running close to 100% load the latter would provide much more time for an operation to be cancelled. Also, I'm not sure how you would check but if the operation is posted as a single IRP then it's either going to cancel or succeed, no in-between.

Comment: @SoronelHaetir,I can publish code if it can help